Phpmyadmin FPM don´t show any style with nginx
I have a small problem with Phpmyadmin-5.2.1-fpm and Nginx.
It don´t show the landing page and all other pages not right.  I only got Text to show on the loaded page.
enter image description here
I found out, that nginx interprets the files as text/html and not text/css like it should be
enter image description here
I think it´s a config thing, but I don´t figure it out why.
My Config is like this:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name pma.to.domain;
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name pma.to.domain;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log combined_ssl;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    root /var/www/html;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/dev-to.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/dev-to.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/certs/dhparams.pem;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    index index.php;
#    charset utf-8;
#    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
#    add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN always;
#    add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;';
#    add_header X-XSS-Protection 0;

    if ($server_protocol ~* "HTTP/1.0") {
       return 444;
    }
    location ~ \themes\.css {
     add_header Content-Type text/css;
    }


#    location / {
#      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
#    }
    location ~* /\.(jpep|png|css|gif|jpg)$ {
     }

    location ~ / {
      fastcgi_pass phpmyadmin:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}

